# 18.04 won't load ohMyZsh.sh source every time

Tags: 18.04, bash, scripts, lubuntu, zsh

I installed zsh and [ohMyZsh](https://ohmyz.sh/) on my system ubuntu desktop 18.04. Although xsh is the default shell, I always have to run the command `source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh` to load the theme.

How can I set up my system so I only run the command one time, instead of every time?

[here](https://pastebin.com/HqXxbqQh) is my .zshrc file

Comment: ubuntu desktop 18.04

Comment: yes it's the default shell

Comment: when I open my terminal it load another theme, only I type source  $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh load the theme in the file .zshrc